# Table structure modifier

Tags: javascript, dom

I have written a JS code to modify the structure of the table by parsing the webpage for particular table class and store the rows of the tables in an array.

And use the array for the constructing a new table. The codes are below.

```
(function() {

    'use strict';

    var headElements = new Array();
    var bodyElements = new Array();
    var tableElement;

    var selector = ".Tabelle-Titel-nur-oben";

    function reinitialize() {
        headElements = [];
        bodyElements = [];
        tableElement;
    }

    function constructTable(reference) {
        tableElement = document.createElement('table');
        var att = document.createAttribute("class"); // Create a "class" attribute
        att.value = "demoTable"; // Set the value of the class attribute
        tableElement.setAttributeNode(att); // Add the class attribute to <h1>
        appendRow(reference);

    }

    function appendRow(reference) {
        var clonedTable = tableElement.cloneNode(true);
        var headClass = document.createAttribute("class");
        headClass.value = 'Zellen-Titel-nur-oben';
        for (var i = 0; i < bodyElements.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < headElements.length; j++) {
                var row = clonedTable.insertRow();
                var clonedRow = row.cloneNode(true);
                var cell0 = clonedRow.insertCell();
                var cloneHeadClass = headClass.cloneNode(true);
                cell0.setAttributeNode(cloneHeadClass);
                cell0.innerHTML = headElements[j].innerHTML;
                var cell1 = clonedRow.insertCell();

                cell1.innerHTML = bodyElements[i][j].innerHTML;
                clonedTable.appendChild(clonedRow);
            }
        }
        document.body.insertBefore(clonedTable, reference);
    }

    function selectTables(selector) {
        var elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            parseHead(elements[i]);
            parseBody(elements[i]);
            constructTable(elements[i]);
            reinitialize();
        }
    }


    function parseHead(nodes) {

        var theadElements = nodes.querySelectorAll('thead');

        for (var i = 0; i < theadElements.length; i++) {
            var rows = theadElements[i]['rows'];
            for (var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
                var children = rows[j]['children'];
                for (var k = 0; k < children.length; k++) {
                    headElements.push(children[k]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function parseBody(nodes) {
        var children = 'children';
        var tbody = 'tbody';
        var tBodyElements = nodes.querySelectorAll(tbody);

        for (var i = 0; i < tBodyElements.length; i++) {
            var tBodyChildren = tBodyElements[i][children];
            for (var j = 0; j < tBodyChildren.length; j++) {
                // row level
                var greatChildren = tBodyChildren[j][children];
                var innerElements = [];
                for (var k = 0; k < greatChildren.length; k++) {
                    innerElements.push(greatChildren[k]);
                }
                bodyElements.push(innerElements);
            }
        }
    }



    selectTables(selector);


})();
```

The table structure:

```
<table id="table-4" class="Tabelle-Titel-nur-oben ng-scope">
    <colgroup>
        <col class="Row-Column-27">
            <col class="Row-Column-27">
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr class="Row-Column-28">
            <td class="Zellen-Titel-nur-oben">
                <p class="Tabelle-Titel-oben">Mensch als Individualwesen</p>
            </td>
            <td class="Zellen-Titel-nur-oben">
                <p class="Tabelle-Titel-oben">Mensch als Sozialwesen</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="Row-Column-29">
            <td class="Zellen-Body-Rows-normal cell-style-override-6">
                <p class="Flie-text-normal"><span class="Fett">Eigene Wünsche</span>
                </p>
                <p class="Flie-text-normal">d.h., der Mensch steht im Mittelpunkt der Betrachtung.</p>
            </td>
            <td class="Zellen-Body-Rows-normal cell-style-override-6">
                <p class="Flie-text-normal"><span class="Fett">Miteinander</span>
                </p>
                <p class="Flie-text-normal">d.h., der Mensch ist von seiner Natur her auf ein soziales Miteinander bezogen und angewiesen.</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="Row-Column-30">
            <td class="Zellen-Body-Rows-normal">
                <p class="Flie-text-normal">individual/individuell (lat.) = einzeln</p>
            </td>
            <td class="Zellen-Body-Rows-normal">
                <p class="Flie-text-normal">socialis (lat.) = gesellschaftlich </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @wOxxOm I have edited and updated the question

Answer (score 2):

The goal is to transpose and flatten the table, so we only have to keep a transposed head array, then just iterate each source row and output one row per each cell prepended with corresponding header cell(s).

This is a very simple and linear transformation, so the code may be linear as well if we replace awkward DOM manipulation with the faster and much simpler [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) along with ES2015 arrow functions for readability (we could use verbose `function` just the same).

```
function transformTables()
{
    let map = (a, fn) => Array.prototype.map.call(a, fn);
    let forEach = (a, fn) => Array.prototype.forEach.call(a, fn);

    forEach(document.querySelectorAll('table.Tabelle-Titel-nur-oben'), table => {
        let head = map(table.tHead.rows[0].cells,
            (cell, i) => map(table.tHead.rows,
                row => row.cells[i].outerHTML
            ).join('')
        );
        table.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin',
            '<table class="demoTable">' + map(table.tBodies,
                body => '<tbody>' + map(body.rows,
                    row => map(row.cells,
                        (cell, i) => '<tr>' + head[i] + cell.outerHTML + '</tr>'
                    ).join('')
                ).join('') +'</tbody>'
            ).join('') + '</table>'
        );
    });
}
```

Comment: does arrow function work in all browsers?

Comment: @forethought No, but transpilers are quite mature these days.

Comment: You can check it by googling "caniuse arrow functions". Not all browsers support them, that's why developers use `babel` and similar transpilers. Anyway, arrow functions were used just as an example here.